# Tickets received, card never charged?

Tags: air-travel, fees-and-charges, expedia

I have a weird one, and I saw [it happened to someone else last year](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173493/flights-booked-and-tickets-issued-but-no-charge-on-my-bank-account), but I don’t see how it played out for them.

I placed tickets for Iberia Airlines a few days back through Expedia on my Apple Card. Initially, it was flagged, I’m assuming because of the size of the purchase. I was able to confirm it was me, and everything went through fine. Along with cancellation insurance.

Yesterday, I decided to pay off the tickets in whole. But now it’s not in my transaction history. Only the cancellation insurance is showing up. Naturally, I’m concerned. So I call Apple/Goldman Sachs to see what’s up. They said the only thing they see is the initial decline. Which is weird, because I have my booking number and everything.

I then called Iberia Airlines. I explain that I wanna makes sure everything is okay, since I don’t wanna get to the airport and something goofy happens, and I can’t board. They assured me everything went through on their end, and they lady was actually kind enough to email me my tickets. But she told me that since the purchase was done through Expedia, they can’t any transaction history. At this point I’m super confused. How do I have these tickets, with no charge on my card, other than the cancellation protection?

Next I call Expedia. Same thing happens. They confirm everything went through on their end. Then they actually send me a confirmation email/receipt. I am now utterly baffled, and REALLY concerned about not being able to board, but I also don’t want to end up buying tickets AGAIN.

So I call Apple again. The lady on the line is now as confused as I am after explaining it all. I even forward the email Expedia sent me, and tell them I have the tickets. I just want to pay it off, and make sure it’s okay. She suggests waiting a day, and calling again if it’s still not there.

I call Apple, and Expedia again today. I essentially get the same responses. I have no idea how concerned I should be right now. I have the tickets. I’m selecting my seats when my girlfriend gets home. But I have no purchase for the tickets on my card. Just the cancellation protection.

Has this happened to anyone else? Will I be able to still board my flight if it doesn’t show up? Have I been charged? I’m so puzzled, and I’m really not looking forward to the idea of showing up to JFK ready to fly, just to be told “nah.” I just wanna pay off my tickets. Any idea how I should go about this? Because I can still select my seats, and add luggage to my tickets/booking. It sincerely seems like I already have the tickets, and trying to buy them again just seems ridiculous.

Comment: Related: [Flights booked and tickets issued but no charge on my bank account?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173493/flights-booked-and-tickets-issued-but-no-charge-on-my-bank-account)

Comment: The previous question “ Flights booked and tickets issued but no charge on my bank account?” is what I’m referring to, but I don’t see how it ever played out for them.

Comment: It would be good to know how *this* plays out.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Delta earlier this year. After a few days my booking simply disappeared from their website.  That was a huge problem since the price had gone up by a factor of 4. Fortunately another few days later, the fare popped back up again at a slightly later date, so I was able to recover.

Comment: Report back and let us know what happens. In the meantime, print _everything_ (including screenshots of Iberia's displaying your ticket and flight info) so you have a tangible record of what occurred.